# Scrapy: Checking the value in a csv file before adding

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I want to check the title of an item in the csv file, and then add to the csv file if it does not exists. I searched almost any responses related to duplicate values. Mostly, they are about `DuplicatesPipeline` and the others did not work for me.

This is my custom pipeline which is the pipelines.py

```
class CheckCsvPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        csv_path = r"C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\ToScrape\book\items.csv"
        self.csvfile = open(csv_path, 'r')
        self.readCsv = csv.reader(self.csvfile, delimiter=',')

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        for row in self.readCsv:
            if item['title'] in row:
                raise DropItem("This title exists: %s" %item)
            else:
                return item
```

Here is my spider:

```
import scrapy

class BooksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'books'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath('//h3/a/@href').extract()
        for book in books:
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_book)

        # process next page
        next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[text()="next"]/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(absolute_next_page_url)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        title = response.css('h1::text').extract_first()
        price = response.xpath('//*[@class="price_color"]/text()').extract_first()

        yield {'title':title, 'price': price}
```

I run the spider with the following code, but it still adds the existing values.

```
scrapy crawl books -o items.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to maintain a list of titles in your spider, and then inside pipeline, check if title already exists in that lists, then do not `yield` it.

```
class CheckCsvPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['title'] in spider.allTitles:

            raise DropItem("This title exists: %s" % item)
        else:

            return item
```

in your spider, do this

```
class BooksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'books'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']

    allTitles = []

    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath('//h3/a/@href').extract()
        for book in books:
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_book)

        # process next page
        next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[text()="next"]/@href').extract_first()
        absolute_next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(absolute_next_page_url)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        title = response.css('h1::text').extract_first()

        self.allTitles.extend([ title ])

        price = response.xpath('//*[@class="price_color"]/text()').extract_first()

        yield {'title':title, 'price': price}
```

Comment: When I yield item in the pipeline, it gives me 'AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'fields'. Instead, I wrote return item, but this time csv file is empty.

Comment: @LandOwner oh sorry, yes you have to use return instead of yield in the pipieline, you didnt get csv? did you run scraper like this `scrapy crawl mySpider -o outputFile.csv`

Comment: Yes I run the spider as you showed but my csv file is always empty. I always get the `This title exists` drop warning. I changed the variable 'allTitles', it stills gives me the same error